# Relation between angles having equal sines

Tags: trigonometry

Given equation such that  $\sin(A) = \sin(B)$. What is relation between angle $A$ and $B$? It is $A=B$ of course. But are there any other conditions?

Comment: Think about this rationally. $A$ and $B$ have the same reference angle, and are either both in quadrants $I$ and/or $II$ (sines are positive) or both in quadrants $III$ and/or $IV$ (sines are negative). Try to scrutinize any answers from this perspective.

Answer (score 1):

As $\sin(2n\pi+x)=x,\sin A=\sin B\implies A=2n\pi+B$ where $n$ is any integer

Again as $\sin(\pi-y)=\sin y, \sin A=\sin B\implies A=2n\pi+\pi-B$

Together $\sin A=\sin B\implies A=m\pi+(-1)^mB$ where $m$ is any integer

Comment: Can u pls explain how have u combined both formulae

Comment: @JessicaGtb,  $A=2n\pi+B=2n\pi+(-1)^{2n}B, A=(2n+1)\pi-B=(2n+1)\pi+(-1)^{2n+1}B$